Used Lacquer Thinner with Polyurethane on cabinets - did I screw up?
I was at Menards and I bought Minwax oil-based polyurethane for some kitchen cabinets. I asked "what do I thin it with?" and the associate gave me "Lacquer Thinner". I did some reading on this online, and it seems like lacquer thinner is aimed at cleaning tools and not thinning polyurethane when putting it on wood.
I haven't done too much with this concoction: first coat on two cabinet doors and the cabinet frames. I have 20 doors left. The poly did go on very thin but is this going to hurt in the long run? What should I be using instead? I tried to go for a mix of 4:1 poly to lacquer thinner.

If you used an oil based polyurethane, lacquer thinner is not inappropriate. Not at all sure what would happen if you added it to water based poly but I suspect nothing goid.
Of course if you thin a varnish it will take more layers to build up equivalent thickness. There are styles where the varnish is kept very thin, but I'm not convinced that minimal protection is as what you want for kitchen cabinet.

I thinned it because I always had problems with bubbles.

You may get better answers about wood finishing in the woodworking stack, though cabinetry is right on the line.

I've taken to applying varnish with a cotton pad rather than a brush, pseudo french polish style. And, yeah, going for more thinner coats.

How many thin coats do you apply? I always see people say 2, but I'm not sure if I should go for more.

Judgement call depending on how it looks/feels, but as rule of thumb I'd go with with 2-3 coats applied normally, 4-5 if applied thinned/thinly. But that really is a better question for the woodworking stack.

It says in the instructions "do not thin" so you're off label on this one.
That said  lacquer thinners is a suitable solvent for thinning most oil-based paints. It also says clean up with mineral spirits, and lacquer thinner is a stronger thinner than mineral spirits so it's not going to turn your paint to snot.
The main advantage you're getting from using lacquer thinners instead of mineral spirts to thin this is faster drying.  You get a better "high" too, but you probably don't want that (ventilate your work area).
